# Mocha and Chai: JSON contains/includes certain text

Tags: mocha.js, chai

Using Mocha and Chai, I am trying to check whether JSON array contains a specific text. I tried multiple things suggested on this site but none worked.

```
  await validatePropertyIncludes(JSON.parse(response.body), 'scriptPrivacy');

  async validatePropertyIncludes(item, propertyValue) {
    expect(item).to.contain(propertyValue);
  }
```

Error that I getting:
**AssertionError: expected [ Array(9) ] to include 'scriptPrivacy'**

My response from API:

```
[
    {
        "scriptPrivacy": {
            "settings": "settings=\"foobar\";",
            "id": "foobar-notice-script",
            "src": "https://foobar.com/foobar-privacy-notice-scripts.js",
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the field is `undefined`.

If field exists in the JSON object, then won't be `undefined`, otherwise yes.

Using `filter()` expresion you can get how many documents don't get `undefined`.

```js
var filter = object.filter(item => item.scriptPrivacy != undefined).length
```

If attribute exists into JSON file, then, variable `filter` should be > 0.

```js
var filter = object.filter(item => item.scriptPrivacy != undefined).length
//Comparsion you want: equal(1) , above(0) ...
expect(filter).to.equal(1)
```

Edit:
To use this method from a method where you pass attribute name by parameter you can use `item[propertyName]` because properties into objects in node can be accessed as an array.

So the code could be:

```js
//Call function
validatePropertyIncludes(object, 'scriptPrivacy')
```

```js
function validatePropertyIncludes(object, propertyValue){
    var filter = object.filter(item => item[propertyValue] != undefined).length
    //Comparsion you want: equal(1) , above(0) ...
    expect(filter).to.equal(1)
}
```

Comment: This works when I do: 
```const filter = items.filter(item => item.scriptPrivacy !== undefined).length;
await expect(filter).to.above(1);  
```
but instead of using item.scriptPrivacy if I try to use the value passed from the calling function then it does not work. This is what I am trying 
```async validatePropertyIncludes(items, propertyValue) { 
const filter = items.filter(item => item.propertyValue !== undefined).length;
await expect(filter).to.above(1); } ```
Calling function:
```await validatePropertyIncludes(JSON.parse(response.body), 'privacyScript');```

Comment: Use ```item[propertyValue]``` insted of ```item.scriptPrivacy```